# Problems with pg_upgradecluster

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, upgrade

Friday I did an upgrade from PostgreSQL 13 to 14 with `pg_upgradecluster` (on Debian Buster). This worked so today I wanted to upgrade another server (Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon). This time it does not work. Here is what I did:

```
root@farao:~# pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
13  main    5432 online postgres /srv/local/postgresql/13    /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-13-main.log
14  main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/14/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log
root@farao:~# pg_dropcluster --stop 14 main
root@farao:~# pg_upgradecluster -V -v 13 main /srv/local/postgresql/data/14
Use of uninitialized value $newversion in string eq at /usr/bin/pg_upgradecluster line 398.
Use of uninitialized value $_[0] in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/PgCommon.pm line 1049.
Stopping old cluster...
Restarting old cluster with restricted connections...
Notice: extra pg_ctl/postgres options given, bypassing systemctl for start operation
Use of uninitialized value $argv[10] in system at /usr/bin/pg_upgradecluster line 461.
Error: invalid version ''
Error: Could not create target cluster
root@farao:~# pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory           Log file
13  main    5432 online postgres /srv/local/postgresql/13 /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-13-main.log
root@farao:~# ps -ef | grep postgres
postgres   24351    1306  0 20:57 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/postgres -D /srv/local/postgresql/13 -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf -c hba_file=/tmp/pg_hba.UabjBQ.conf
postgres   24353   24351  0 20:57 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 13/main: checkpointer 
postgres   24354   24351  0 20:57 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 13/main: background writer 
postgres   24355   24351  0 20:57 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 13/main: walwriter 
postgres   24356   24351  0 20:57 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 13/main: autovacuum launcher 
postgres   24357   24351  0 20:57 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 13/main: stats collector 
postgres   24358   24351  0 20:57 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 13/main: logical replication launcher 
root       24488   18929  0 20:58 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto postgres
root@farao:~# cat /tmp/pg_hba.UabjBQ.conf
local all postgres ident
root@farao:~# pg_upgradecluster -V -v 13 main /srv/local/postgresql/data/14
Use of uninitialized value $newversion in string eq at /usr/bin/pg_upgradecluster line 398.
Use of uninitialized value $_[0] in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/PgCommon.pm line 1049.
Stopping old cluster...
Restarting old cluster with restricted connections...
Notice: extra pg_ctl/postgres options given, bypassing systemctl for start operation
Use of uninitialized value $argv[10] in system at /usr/bin/pg_upgradecluster line 461.
Error: invalid version ''
Error: Could not create target cluster
root@farao:~# pg_upgradecluster
Usage: /usr/bin/pg_upgradecluster [OPTIONS] <old version> <cluster name> [<new data directory>]
root@farao:~#
```

Without the `-V` parameter, the result is the same. What did I do wrong? Do I need to install a PERL module?

*remark* I just remembered that I only installed postgresql-13 and used the database and configuration that was still present. Does PostgreSQL store somewhere information about the clusters that it created with `initdb`? Not logical because `pg_lsclusters` can find it.

Comment: Does simple command `pg_upgradecluster 13 main` work ? Can you try same command without dropping `14 main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read in the `man` page of `pg_upgradecluster`, there might be a typo in your command.

Here is the synopsis from the man page:

```
pg_upgradecluster [-v newversion] oldversion name [newdatadir]
```

Either keep `-v` and explicitly add the new version number :

```
pg_upgradecluster -V -v 14 13 main /srv/local/postgresql/data/14
```

or remove `-v` altogether (will default to the latest available version) :

```
pg_upgradecluster -V 13 main /srv/local/postgresql/data/14
```

Comment: Was a typo :-( The command `pg_upgradecluster -v 14 13 main /srv/local/postgresql/data/14` worked like a charm. You deserve the bounty.